# Low Pass Filter for Android Pressure Sensor

Tags: android, filter, sensors, pressure

Have tried to adapt the android developer documentation for accelerator LPF but it does not seem to work with pressure

```
    float pressure_value = 0.0f;
    float height = 0.0f;
    float height2 = (float) 964.98;
    final float alpha = (float) 0.8;


    if( Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE == event.sensor.getType() ) {
        pressure_value = event.values[0];
        event.values[0] = alpha * event.values[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
        event.values[1] = alpha * event.values[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
        event.values[2] = alpha * event.values[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];
```

does anyone have some insight?

Comment: can u elaborate your problem? Like how its not working? or any error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pressure sensor only has one value i.e. event.values[0]. A simple low pass filter for that would look like:

```
pressure = alpha*event.values[0] + (1 - alpha)*pressure
```

***Extremely*** oversimplified explanation:

For alpha=0.8, the 'new' pressure value is 80% of the actual current pressure supplied by the sensor + 20% of the value of the 'old' pressure. Increasing the alpha value will make it more responsive to pressure fluctuations, lower alpha values will make it less noisy (more filtered).

More explanatory code:

```
private float alpha = 0.8f; 
private float filteredPressure = 0.0f; 

@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
   if (Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE == event.sensor.getType()) { 
      float currentPressure = event.values[0]; 
      filteredPressure = (alpha*currentPressure) + (1 - alpha)*filteredPressure; 
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry for my ignorance (the only java i use is restfullAPIs in spring)  but would i just add the filter on top of the defined pressure_value  variable?

so for example:

pressure_value = alpha*event.values[0] + (1 - alpha)* pressure

still trying to figure out the markup on some of this

Comment: `float filtered_pressure = 0.0f;
        float pressure_value = 0.0f;
        float height = 0.0f;
        float refHeight = 964.9f;
        float alpha = 0.1f;


        if( Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE == event.sensor.getType() ) {
            pressure_value = event.values[0];
            filtered_pressure = (alpha*event.values[0]) + ((1 - alpha)*event.values[0]);`




FWIW this returns the same noisy value for both filtered pressure and pressure_value

Comment: Thank you so much!  i actually figured that out last night but i appreciate you coming back and writing that out!   

it hit me when i did the basic math of what i had and plugged some numbers into it.

thanks again !

Comment: ***  update ***   still doesn't work... at a loss. maybe java development isnt in the cards for me lol

*** double update ******

moving the alpha and the filteredpressure variables outside of the onsensor changed event fixed it. is this a java thing?

Comment: Uh, no .. it's a logic thing :-)